# Cannot add an event to the calendar in android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Whenever I am trying to add event to the android mobile calendar the following message is displayed:

> "Before you can add an event, you must add at least one Calendar account to the device and > make a calendar visible. Touch 'Add account' to add an account (if you just added an 
>   account, wait for it to finish syncing and try again). Or touch Cancel and ensure that at 
>   least one calendar is visible."

Answer (score -1):

Please go to calendar page and click the date and after once sec again click the that date. Now open on alert message, cancel this alert. Again show another alert, if you alreday create the google account means cancel this alert also else if you just add an account. Finally  you get event create page please check it.